# Linux platrform cross compiling pulseaudio for arm architecture

Tags: cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I am cross compiling pulseaudio package for arm architechture on linux platform .while cross compiling it is asking for shared libraries such as glib2.0 from other package i want to know that this dependent shared library should also be cross compiled and given to pulse audio while cross compiling? Are some shared library *.so are generic for example for x86 and arm ?

Answer (score 0):

No, .so files are architecture specific and you have to compile them for arm before you use it for cross-compilation.

Answer (score 0):

`dependent shared library should also be cross compiled and given to pulse audio while cross compiling?` 
No. For cross compiling, there are some dependency. So install them again try to cross compile your code.

```
Are some shared library *.so are generic for example for x86 and arm ?
```

As you know, both are different architecture. Same shared library cannot be used on both. Need to be specifically compiled for each architecture.